# Play! framework - handle a POST request

Tags: java, http, web, playframework-2.0, web-development-server

this is the route to handle the login POST request:

```
POST  /login/submit                 controllers.Users.loginSubmit(user : String, password : String)
```

this is the login.scala.html:

```
<form method="post" action="???">
  <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="password" /><br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

I got two questions:

1. what should be the value of action?  is it "login/submit"?
2. how do you pass this form to be handled in the loginSubmit function?

thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If it's `POST` form, you don't need to declare params in the `route`:

```
POST  /login/submit           controllers.Users.loginSubmit()
```

Template:

```
<!-- syntax: @routes.ControllerName.methodName() -->
<form method="post" action="@routes.Users.loginSubmit()">
  <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="password" /><br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Import:

```
import play.data.DynamicForm;
import play.data.Form;
```

Controller:

```
public static Result loginSubmit(){
    DynamicForm dynamicForm = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
    Logger.info("Username is: " + dynamicForm.get("username"));
    Logger.info("Password is: " + dynamicForm.get("password"));
    return ok("ok, I recived POST data. That's all...");
}
```

### Template form helpers

There are also [form template helpers](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaFormHelpers) available for creating forms in Play's template so the same can be done as:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.User.loginSubmit()) {
    <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" /><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

They are especially useful when working with large and/or `pre-filled` forms

Comment: Does it work also for Scala? For me doesn't work with POST and I have to switch to GET requests, because there is nothing in the object request

Comment: Getting the form didn't work for me with "form().bindFromRequest();" 
Got to use "Form.form().bindFromRequest();" as shown here http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms

Comment: Answer was written for Play 2.0.x and in 2.1.x it was refactored by the team, anyway that's not problem as well as you can just use proper import... `import static play.data.Form.form;`

Answer (score 5):

In Play Framework version 2.5.x [Form.form() is deprecated](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.0/api/java/play/data/Form.html) and you should use [**inject a FormFactory**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.0/api/java/play/data/FormFactory.html)

Here you can find example: [The method form(Class) from Form class is deprecated in Play! Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36114338/6309821)

Import:

```
import play.data.DynamicForm;
import play.data.FormFactory;
```

Inject:

```
@Inject FormFactory formFactory;
```

Controller:

```
public static Result loginSubmit(){
    DynamicForm dynamicForm = formFactory.form().bindFromRequest();
    Logger.info("Username is: " + dynamicForm.get("username"));
    Logger.info("Password is: " + dynamicForm.get("password"));
    return ok("ok, I recived POST data. That's all...");
}
```