# How to convert the play.api.mvc.Call to Class[?]?

Tags: java, forms, playframework, playframework-2.0

Ｉ am new in play and meet the error is:

```
[error] F:\Kepler\wefarm\app\views\login.scala.html:8: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.Call
[error]  required: Class[?]
[error]    @form(routes.Session.authenticate()) {
[error]                                     ^
```

I defined the authenticate function inside the Session.java

```
public class Session extends Controller {
....
public static Result authenticate() {
    Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
        return redirect(routes.Session.login());
    } else {
        session("connected", loginForm.get().email);
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }
}
...
}
```

The error happens on the login.scala.html:

```
@(loginForm: Form[Session.Login])

@import play.data.Form.form
@main("WeFarm") {  
<h1>Farmer login</h1>
@form(routes.Session.authenticate()) {    ///////------error   happens here
@inputText(farmerForm("email"), '_label -> "Email")
@inputPassword(farmerForm("password"), '_label -> "Password")
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
```

}

I want put authenticate result into form, the form do not recognize it.
how to make the @form accept the result?

Comment: I'm still teaching my self play, but don't you need to assign the reverse route to the action, as per this [example](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059147/play-framework-handle-a-post-request) may also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you need to assign the result to a form parameter

```
@form(action = routes.Session.authenticate()) {
```

You can check the [documentation/example](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers) and this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059147/play-framework-handle-a-post-request) for more details

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will make clear that I don't know about Play framework. But you can get the class from the `getClass()` method

```
@form(routes.Session.authenticate().getClass())
```

Do refer what you need to pass in the `@form` annotation.